# Algebra precalculus factorization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I must factor this out:$(a+1)(a+3)(a+5)(a+7)+15$
I know that it might have an artifice or technique to transform those factors, but i cannot find any idea on how to do it.

PS.The majority of my questions are about factoring polynomials. Is there an app or site on internet where I can see step by step the resolution of these exercices so then I won't bother you guys anymore with a lot of these kind of silly questions?

Comment: Multiply $(a+1)(a+7)=a^2+8a+7$ and $(a+3)(a+5)=a^2+8a+15$. Replace $y=a^2+8a+7$. You get $y(y+8)+15$. Factor that one. And then factor the two factors you get after replacing $y$ by $a^2+8a+7$.

Comment: try this here $$(a+2)(a+6)(a^2+8a+10)$$

Comment: It is the same trick I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2701787/541228) in the first comment. It takes advantage that the numbers $1,3,5,7$ form an arithmetic progression, and therefore the sum of the first and last $1+7=8$ equals the sum of the second and second to last $3+5=8$. The trick reduces the degree of the equation by $2$. But since the original degree was $4$ that leaves us with degree $2$ which we know how to factors using the quadratic formula.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

take $$ b = a+4  $$
$$ (b-3)(b-1)(b+1)(b+3) + 15 $$
$$ (b-1)(b+1)(b-3)(b+3) + 15 $$
$$ (b^2-1)(b^2-9) + 15 $$
$$  b^4 - 10 b^2 + 9 + 15  $$
$$  b^4 - 10 b^2 + 24  $$

take $u = b^2$
$$ u^2 - 10 u + 24 $$
$$  (u - 4)(u - 6)  $$

$$  (b^2 - 4)(b^2 - 6)  $$
$$  (a^2 + 8 a + 16 - 4) (a^2 + 8 a + 16 - 6) $$

$$  (a^2 + 8 a + 12) (a^2 + 8 a + 10) $$

$$  (a + 6)(a+2) (a^2 + 8 a + 10) $$

The roots of $a^2 + 8 a + 10$ are real numbers but not rational, $-4 \pm \sqrt 6$